# CountUp.js to create a counter for days and hours

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to create a counter like [this one](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/) to count up the values up to a number which represents the hours. What I want to do with it is to show it in f.e. **3d13h** format (days and hours) where I want the startValue to be 0d0h and to count up one day for every 24 hours, after which the original hour counter should be reset and repeated for number of days.

This is what I have for now, but in my example for 220.55 number of hours the for loop does not run correct number of times and I can't seem to create an animation for the remaining number of hours (value % 24) because when I try with an .update function from [documentation](https://github.com/inorganik/CountUp.js) it overwrites my whole countUp object. Any help would be appreciated :)

app.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CountUp } from 'countup.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  options;
  countUp: CountUp;

  @Input() startValue: number;
  dayCount: number = 0;

  ngOnInit () {

    this.startValue = 220.55;

    const totalDays = Math.round(Math.floor(this.startValue / 24));
    const totalHours = this.startValue % 24;

    this.options = {
      decimalPlaces: 2,
      duration: 0.15,
      prefix: this.dayCount.toString() + "d",
      suffix: "h"
    }

    this.countUp = new CountUp('counterClass', 24, this.options);

    for(let i=0; i<totalDays; i++) {
      this.countUp.start(
        () => {
        this.dayCount++;
        this.countUp.options.prefix = this.dayCount.toString() + 'd';
        this.countUp.reset();
      }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<div>
  <div style="font-size: 100px; 
  color: cadetblue; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;">{{days}}</div>
  <div 
  id="counterClass" 
  style="font-size: 100px; 
  color: cadetblue; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;"
  ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether below solution will fit your requirement. If not you might need to tweak the code to your requirement.

The is to seperate days and hours and on completion of days, execute hours.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { CountUp } from "countup.js";
import { CountUpOptions } from "./interfaces/count-up";
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  totalDays = 0;
  balanceHours = 0;
  daysOptions: CountUpOptions = {
    start: this.totalDays,
    suffix: "D",
    duration: 2,
    separator: ""
  };
  hoursOptions: CountUpOptions = {
    start: this.totalDays,
    suffix: "H",
    duration: 2,
    separator: ""
  };
  @ViewChild("targetDays") targetDays: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("targetHours") targetHours: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    const totalHours = 220.55;
    this.totalDays = parseInt(totalHours / 24);
    this.balanceHours = parseInt(totalHours % 24);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.countUpDays();
  }

  countUpDays() {
    const countUpDays = new CountUp(
      this.targetDays.nativeElement,
      this.totalDays,
      this.daysOptions
    );
    if (countUpDays.error) {
      return;
    }
    countUpDays.start(() => this.countUpHours());
  }

  countUpHours() {
    const countUpHours = new CountUp(
      this.targetHours.nativeElement,
      this.balanceHours,
      this.hoursOptions
    );
    if (countUpHours.error) {
      return;
    }
    countUpHours.start();
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happ :)
</p>

<div #targetDays></div>
<div #targetHours></div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s96myj)

Comment: Hey Alaksandar, thanks for replying :) I like your solution too, even though it is not what I imagined and started coding in the first place. Only thing I would like to change is the "pause" that happens when day count stops, right before the start of hour count up. Also, for the number of hours that is less than one day, countUp for days still counts it as one day. Great job!